# Why do I get &#39 when typing ' in HTMLAgilityPack (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack, quotes

I am using HTMLAGilityPack to edit web page, and it seems I am getting quotes replaced with &#39 or " etc.

Why is this happening and how to fix?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1115718/120955) is likely related. The webpage encoding maybe isn't directly translatable to .NET's UTF-16 string encoding, so HTMLAgilityPack translates the characters into their decimal encodings to preserve their meaning in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is being encoded. Try using Html.Raw() to decode.

Comment: at what point would I use that? When I load the html source into the document? Or when I save out? I've tried both but doesn't work. BTW I'm using Blazor so using Markupstring i.e. myDoc.LoadHtml(((MarkupString)myHTMLSource).ToString());

Comment: Hmmm, not familiar with blazor but it would be when you're loading the HTML. It would read like Html.Raw(htmlToRead)

Comment: ya that's how I'm doing it, and if I look at the code as it loads, it's fine, it's just when I use a WYSIWYG to edit the page, the quotes change like I said. So not sure if the problem is with the agility pack or the WSYIWYG