# How do you create an indented XML string from an XDocument in c#?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have an XDocument object and the ToString() method returns XML without any indentation. How do I create a string from this containing indented XML?

edit: I'm asking how to create an in memory string rather than writing out to a file.

edit: Looks like I accidentally asked a trick question here... ToString() does return indented XML.

Comment: Can you post your code? The only way I can get XDocument.ToString to NOT indent the XML is when I explicitly pass in SaveOptions.DisableFormatting to the ToString method.

Comment: I tried the answers here. They had no effect (still uses spaces). Using .Net 4 (not client).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123718/format-xml-string-to-print-friendly-xml-string

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
string indented = doc.ToString();
```

Comment: This works fine. `XDocument.ToString()` formats with indentation by default. To get unformatted output, you have to go out of your way by calling `.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting)`

Comment: I was actually looking for disabling. Thanks @JoelMueller

Answer (score 9):

From [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/erikaehrli/archive/2005/11/16/IndentXMLFilesandDocuments.aspx)

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<item><name>wrench</name></item>");

// Save the document to a file and auto-indent the output.
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("data.xml",null);
writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
doc.Save(writer);
```

Comment: The question is how to create a string, not how to create a file.

Comment: @JC: Use a StringWriter instead of the file name in the XmlTextWriter's constructor to get a string.

Comment: -1: Do not use `new XmlTextWriter()` or `new XmlTextReader()` past .NET 1.1. Use `XmlWriter.Create()` or `XmlReader.Create()`.

Answer (score 7):

Just one more flavor of the same soup... ;-)

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
XmlTextWriter xw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
xw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
doc.WriteTo(xw);
Console.WriteLine(sw.ToString());
```

Edit: thanks to [John Saunders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76337/john-saunders). Here is a version that should better conform to [Creating XML Writers on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz7cs0d.aspx).

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XDocument doc = new XDocument(
        new XComment("This is a comment"),
        new XElement("Root",
            new XElement("Child1", "data1"),
            new XElement("Child2", "data2")
            )
            );

        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings()
        {
            Indent = true
        };
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(builder, settings))
        {
            doc.WriteTo(writer);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Prefer this to mine, but where's your usings?!

Comment: -1: Do not use new XmlTextWriter() or new XmlTextReader() past .NET 1.1. Use XmlWriter.Create() or XmlReader.Create()

Answer (score 6):

To create a string using an XDocument (rather than an XmlDocument), you can use:

```
        XDocument doc = new XDocument(
            new XComment("This is a comment"),
            new XElement("Root",
                new XElement("Child1", "data1"),
                new XElement("Child2", "data2")
            )
        );

        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlTextWriter.Create(sb, settings)) {
            doc.WriteTo(writer);
            writer.Flush();
        }
        string outputXml = sb.ToString();
```

**Edit:** Updated to use `XmlWriter.Create` and a `StringBuilder` and good form (`using`).

Comment: -1: Do not use new XmlTextWriter() or new XmlTextReader() past .NET 1.1. Use XmlWriter.Create() or XmlReader.Create()

Comment: Thanks, I'd missed that.  I updated the sample accordingly (and reduced complexity with a StringBuilder at the same time!)

Comment: FYI, on review, I still want to keep my downvote because you didn't use a `using` block.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Thanks again and updated again. I suspect I was originally trying to focus on the basic behavior, but sloppy samples tend to end up in sloppy code somewhere else.