# How do I replace multiple tags in a string based on conditions?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a XML file and I need to do some replacements before the main process, so I am using `StringBuilder` to read line by line and make the necessary changes. One of them is as follows:

My string is:
`<para>This<brk/>is<brk/>a<brk/>bold tag.</para> // Simple Input`

I am separating each  into a new line. So each  will be:

`<para>This</para>
<para>is</para>
<para>a</para>
<para>bold tag.</para>`

Now, if I have a `<bold>` or `<italic>` tag in the `<para>` tag, then ideally it should be:
`<para><bold>This<brk/>is<brk/>a<brk/>bold tag.</bold></para> // Main Input`

But in my case, I have to separate each  into separate lines, so this will be an invalid syntax. According to my requirement, it should be:
`<para><bold>This</bold><brk/><bold>is</bold><brk/><bold>a</bold><brk/><bold>bold tag.</bold></para> // Required Input`

How do I check for each `<brk/>` tag to make sure that each `<brk/>` is replaced by `<bold><brk/></bold>`.

The thing is that `<bold>` tags can come anywhere in the string. For example:
`<para><bold>This</bold> again<brk/> is<brk/><bold> a <brk/>paragraph</bold></para> // Another Input`

Now, if I split this according to the split rule that I am using, it wil become:
`<para><bold>This</bold>again</para>
<para>is</para>
<para><bold>a</para>            // Line 1
<para>bold tag.</bold></para>   // Line 2`

`Line 1` and `Line 2` are invalid XML lines.

In this case the output will be:
`<para><bold>This</bold> again<brk/> is<brk/><bold> a </bold><brk/><bold>paragraph</bold></para>`.

If I don't do this replacement, the XML will be invalid as I have to split the string to a new line at every `<brk/>` tag.

Comment: Unless you are working with crappy third party interfaces, there is no need in separating the XML nodes in different lines. .NET XML related classes work fine without line breaks.

Comment: Actually, I am working on an application and it is the requirement so I will take a XML file as an input and check for a few tags.

I will then replace them as required. This is one of the requirements.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374654/how-do-you-create-an-indented-xml-string-from-an-xdocument-in-c) help? I'm not sure if understood your question.

Comment: Why dont you work with XML related classes? That `<brk/>` logic could be done fairly easy with recursion and a replacement of the XML node inner text.

Comment: @PrimoChalice I would double check your requirements, because single line XML vs well formatted XML... It is still valid XML

Comment: Diego Penha and bradbury9, I believe I am unable to explain the question properly.

So, basically the `<bold>` or `<italic>` tag can come anywhere in the string. I just need to check the format. If not matched, then just change it as mentioned in the question.

Comment: It is like, I need to check the number of `<brk/>` tags in the string and then the `<bold>` or `<italic>` tags, both opening and closing. I have to make sure that if I split the string in multiple lines, the XML should not be invalid.

Comment: Jamie Rees, actually that is the issue. If a tag is opened in line 1 and closed in line 2, it is invalid, right? That is the issue I want to resolve.

Comment: @PrimoChalice - No. You could open a tag on the first and close it on the hundredth and still be valid (of course, it depends on what the XML is...). Also FYI, you can respond to specific users here with an "@" before their name.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb - Sorry, my bad. Also, I am getting the following error:
`The 'bold' start tag on line 18 position 8 does not match the end tag of 'para'. Line 18, position 15.'`

`<para><bold>This</bold> again</para> // Line 16
<para> is</para> // Line 17
<para><bold> a </para> // Line 18
<para>paragraph</bold></para> // Line 19`

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient solution you will find there, but you can give this a try:

```
string FormatLine(string xmlLine)
{
    var xmlBoldLine = GetFormattedString(xmlLine, "bold");
    var xmlitalicLine = GetFormattedString(xmlBoldLine, "italic");

    return xmlitalicLine;
}

string GetFormattedString(string xmlLine, string tag)
{
    if (xmlLine.Contains(tag))
    {
        return "<" + tag + ">" + xmlLine.Replace(tag, "") + "</" + tag + ">";
    }

    return xmlLine;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using a string method to modify xml.  Use one of the standard Net Xml Libraries like Xml Linq shown below

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;



namespace ConsoleApplication104
{
    class Program
    {


         static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = "<root><para>This<brk/>is<brk/>a<brk/>bold tag.</para></root>";

            XElement root = XElement.Parse(xml);

            XElement para = root.Element("para");

            List<XElement> children = para.Elements().ToList();
            foreach (XElement child in children)
            {
                root.Add(new XElement("para", child.NextNode.ToString()));
            }
             children.Remove();

        }
    }
}
```