# how to display XML?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

```
    WebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://example.com/example");
    WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
    string str = sr.ReadToEnd();
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(str);
    XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("D://myGameSite//myGames.xml", null);
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    doc.Save(writer);**strong text**
    Response.Write(doc);
```

now this code is working perfectly I mean it saves the XML file in the root directory of the myGameSite with the file named myGames, but when I try to display this XML file in browser as you can see in the code, it just plainly displays this

```
    System.Xml.XmlDocument
```

I want to display this XML file in my browser along with the tags, and the version of my asp.net and .netframework is 2.0 so please I can't use LINQ :(

Comment: by display you mean opening the file with a browser..??

Comment: Why double-slashes in the file-path?

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro yes I mean oppening the file in browser

Comment: @MarcGravell because of escape sequences, I didn't know any other to make it work

Comment: @mamoorkhan - you don't have to escape a forward slash `/`, but you do need to escape the more usual (in a Windows path) backslash `\\`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will do ;)

```
Response.Write("<pre><code>" + Server.HtmlEncode(doc.InnerXml) + "</code></pre>");
```

**EDIT**

Or you can display the xml in a textarea

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtXml" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="500px" Width="600px" />
```

Code behind

```
// This will preserve indentation 
    txtXml.Text = doc.InnerXml;
```

Comment: this isn't helping with the indentation either :(

Comment: @mamoorkhan - see edit. added pre tag which will preserve indentation or you can use a textarea to display xml as such...

Answer (score 1):

in your last row use

```
Response.Write(doc.InnerXml);
```

Comment: its displaying it, but without any tags, below is the example data that is being shown in the browser

100510a0AF0000006oO0lMAETC15740truefalse220000.00

these are different nodes data

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the xml available, as `str`, just write that:

```
Response.Write(str);
```

note that this won't include any formatting changes - if you need that, you'll either need to *write* the xml again (to the output), or load the file you just wrote. You'll also want to change the response-type to "text/xml". Unrelated, but note you should also **close** the writer, ideally with `using`:

```
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;
using(var writer = XmlWriter.Create(path, settings)) {
  doc.Save(writer);
}
```

You could also repeat the `Save`:

```
using(var writer = XmlWriter.Create(Response.Output, settings)) {
  doc.Save(writer);
}
```

Comment: yeah I did that too, but that was too just displaying nodes data without any indentation

Comment: @mamoorkhan yes, but the only place you wrote it with indentation was to the file... so you will either need to use `File.ReadAllText`, or **separately**, repeat the `doc.Save`, but to the output stream (see edit)

Answer (score 1):

google "pretty print xml c#"; e.g. http://www.expertcore.org/viewtopic.php?t=1101

you'll find working code, I'm sure. Here's one example: [Format XML String to Print Friendly XML String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123718/format-xml-string-to-print-friendly-xml-string)

pass `doc.OuterXml` to that function that you find; it'll spit out indented xml

set this xml to some multiline textbox in readonly more or some label; unless it's textbox/textarea, you'll have to html-encode it (e.g. for a label):

`this.someLabel.Text = this.Server.HtmlEncode(prettyPrintedXml)`

Answer (score 1):

For those who uses C# as back-end and angular as front-end mcv framework the following code will work (kind of a workaround).

```
[BACK-END]
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Xml;
//-----
public ActionResult QueryGenerator(string naturalQuery)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(path_to_xml);
    string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);

    return Json( new{xmlString = jsonText}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

[JAVASCRIPT]
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: baseUrl + 'QueryGenerator',
    params: params
}).
  success(function (data, status, config) {
      $scope.xmlList = JSON.parse(data.xmlString);
  }).
  error(function (data, status, config) {
     alert('error');
  });

[HTML]
<xmp ng-repeat="node in xmlList track by $index">
    <Discource>
        <Token>
            <Term>{{node.Term}}</Term>
            <PosTag>{{node.PosTag}}</PosTag>
            <Restriction>{{node.Restriction}}</Restriction>
            <Synonyms>{{node.Synonyms}}</Synonyms>
        </Token>
    </Discource>
</xmp>
```

[image]

Comment: <XMP> all your xml goes here </XMP>     is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: As D. Kermott stated, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you, Charitha.

Answer (score 0):

Use [XmlDatasource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xmldatasource%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and Data Controls (GridView/Repeator) to show XML document data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
 <root>
   <foo>
     <bar>One</bar>
   </foo>
   <foo>
     <bar>Two</bar>
   </foo>
 </root>
```

Markup:

```
<asp:XmlDataSource
    runat="server"
    id="XmlDataSource1"
    XPath="root/foo"
    DataFile="file.xml" />

<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1"
    runat="server"
    DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <h2>Bar :<%#XPath("bar")%> </h2>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: `        <asp:XmlDataSource runat="server" id="XmlDataSource1"    XPath="root/searchResult" DataFile="data.xml" />
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <h2>Bar :<%#XPath("bar")%> </h2>
            </ItemTemplate>`

I tried to use the code 

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<searchResult>`
<other too many nodes>
</searchResult>`

but it isn't displaying anything

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
    public static string IndentedPrint(XmlDocument doc)
    {
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.Unicode))
            {
                xmlTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

                doc.WriteContentTo(xmlTextWriter);
                xmlTextWriter.Flush();
                memoryStream.Flush();

                memoryStream.Position = 0;

                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
                {
                    return sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the XMP tag...  it will indent and make your xml almost look pretty!

```
<XMP>
  <po>
    <BeginningSegment_BEG>
      <TransactionSetPurposeCode_01>00</TransactionSetPurposeCode_01>
      <PurchaseOrderTypeCode_02>NE</PurchaseOrderTypeCode_02>
      <PurchaseOrderNumber_03>PO01183082</PurchaseOrderNumber_03>
      <Date_05>2016-12-14</Date_05>
    </BeginningSegment_BEG>
  </po>
</XMP>
```

and it will look like this in your browser:
[image: xmp output]

It worked for me in Chrome and IE