# How do you indent and format an XML file in a Win 8 app?

Tags: xml, formatting, microsoft-metro, c++-cx

I've got some code that generates an Windows::Data::Xml::Dom::XmlDocument^ in a win 8 app

```
XmlDocument^ document = ref new XmlDocument();

auto A = document->CreateElement("elemA");
document->AppendChild(A);

auto B = document->CreateElement("elemB");
auto C = document->CreateElement("elemC");
A->AppendChild(B);
A->AppendChild(C);
```

And then I save to a file using

```
document->SaveToFileAsync(file); // file is not important
```

And the result I get is

```
<elemA><elemB/><elemC/></elemA>
```

Whereas I'm looking for

```
<elemA>
   <elemB/>
   <elemC/>
</elemA>
```

How can I format the Xml to have proper indentation when nesting nodes? I tried searching but couldn't find any relevant examples for a Win 8 app and C++/CX. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1123947/1230188, might be helpful, but it is in C#

Comment: I tried using XmlTextWriter but I can't find it in the C++/CX APIs, it must be C# only. Thanks though.