# How to get readable xml from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

How can I get readable xml string from a SQL Server database?

In this way I get xml string, then set it to ExtJs textarea. But text is not readable:

```
public string GetXml(string args)
{
    string exMsg = "";
    string result = "";
    StringBuilder xmlResult = new StringBuilder();

    Dictionary<string, object> parameters = _ser.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(args);
    string Id = parameters["Id"].ToString();

    try
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection cn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();

        cn.ConnectionString = "data source=(local);initial catalog=MethodSettings;User ID=sa;Password=sasa";

        cn.Open();

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT MethodArgs FROM  MethodSettings.dbo.MethodParameters  WHERE Id ={0}", Id);

        System.Xml.XmlReader xmlr = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();

        xmlr.Read();

        if (xmlr != null)
        {
            xmlResult.AppendLine(xmlr.ReadOuterXml());
            result = xmlResult.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         exMsg = ex.Message;
    }

    return _ser.Serialize(result);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123718/format-xml-string-to-print-friendly-xml-string

Comment: what do you mean exactly by '*not readable*'? can you give example XML you expect to see and what actually get displayed?

Comment: for example i get : <note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>                                                                                                     
I want to get like here: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s [`ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to get formatted XML string easily, if that's what you actually want to get :

```
System.Xml.XmlReader xmlr = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlr);
doc.Load(xmlr);​

var result = doc.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
            System.Xml.XmlReader xmlr = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(xmlr);​
```