# Formatting XML data in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, formatting, indentation

I've been looking for a while, but I seem not able to find a solution.. 
I am building XElement with Linq and everything is being nicely aligned except when I try to linebreak Xelement.Value into multiple lines..

My codes looks like:

```
var result = new XElement("Items",
new XAttribute("ID", id),
new XElement("ItemsA", $"\n{string.Join(",\n", ItemsA.Select(x => x.Value))}\n"),
new XElement("ItemsB", $"\n{string.Join(",\n", ItemsB.Select(x => x.Value))}\n"));
```

The output of the result looks like:

```
<Items ID="123123">
  <ItemsA>
items1a,
items2a,
</ItemsA>
  <ItemsB>
items1b,
items2b,
</ItemsB>
</Items>
```

my question is - how can I make it format/indent it correctly?

I have tried changing `$"\n\t{string.Join(",\n\t", ItemsA.Select(x => x.Value))}\n\t"` but then it is tabbed further away then the rest of the tags..

What I am trying to achieve is:

```
<Items ID="123123">
   <ItemsA>
      items1a,
      items2a,
   </ItemsA>
   <ItemsB>
      items1b,
      items2b,
   </ItemsB>
</Items>
```

I also tried:

```
private static XElement FormatXml(XElement input)
        {
            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;

            var builder = new StringBuilder(input.ToString());

            using(var writer = XmlWriter.Create(builder, settings))
            {
                input.WriteTo(writer);
            }
            return input;
        }
```

but it was no luck either.

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this. Take a look at the following posts answer for more information:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123718/format-xml-string-to-print-friendly-xml-string

Comment: Did you try without all the '\n's?  You should be able to save using result.WriteXml("filename");

Comment: Hey, I tried the approaches suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123718/format-xml-string-to-print-friendly-xml-string but I end up getting the same result.. 
I think the issue is that I want xelement.value be split across multiple lines and that is all it does without allignment..