# Split values from a string

Tags: c#

I have xml data in a string and i want it to split and i want to display the result in a Lable.

Here is my code:

```
string param = <HCToolParameters><BatchId>12</BatchId><HCUser>Admin</HCUser</HCToolParameters>;
var a = param.Split(new string[] { "<HCToolParameters>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var b = param.Split(new string[] { "<BatchId>12</BatchId>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var c = param.Split(new string[] { "<HCUser>Admin</HCUser>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var d = param.Split(new string[] { "</HCToolParameters>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Example:

```
String value = 
<HCToolParameters><BatchId>12</BatchId><HCUser>Admin</HCUser></HCToolParameters>
```

Expected Result:

```
<HCToolParameters>
 <BatchId>12</BatchId>
 <HCUser>Admin</HCUser>
</HCToolParameters>
```

Comment: Why 2 of your tags in the string are not close ?

Comment: @mybirthname even worse, it's 3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format XML String to Print Friendly XML String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123718/format-xml-string-to-print-friendly-xml-string)

Answer (score 1):

From what I see in the begging you have valid xml so, stop spliting it and use Xml Parser !

```
string param =@"<HCToolParameters><BatchId>12</BatchId><HCUser>Admin</HCUser></HCToolParameters>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(param);

Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could do it easy by this:

```
value = value.Replace("><", ">" + Environment.NewLine + "<");
```

This would work out in your example and is easy,... if you need it as Array (I don't realy know why you would try it this way:

```
var array = value.Replace("><", ">#<").Split('#');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XmlTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;` because what is see is, you wanted to format your XML string. This function might do the trick for you

```
public static String FormatMyXML(String SomeXML)
{
    String Result = "";
    MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
    XmlTextWriter wrtr = new XmlTextWriter(mStream, Encoding.Unicode);
    XmlDocument document   = new XmlDocument();
    try
    {
        document.LoadXml(SomeXML);
        wrtr.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        document.WriteContentTo(wrtr);
        wrtr.Flush();
        mStream.Flush();
        mStream.Position = 0;
        StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(mStream);
        String FormattedXML = sReader.ReadToEnd();
        Result = FormattedXML;
    }
    catch (XmlException)
    {
    }
    mStream.Close();
    wrtr.Close();
    return Result;
}
```