# XML string formatting C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have following xml string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <reportResponse>
      <report>
        <inquiry>
          <agencyId>32</agencyId>
          <archiveId>4055062521111790</archiveId>
          <originalArchiveId>0</originalArchiveId>
          <sequenceNr>0</sequenceNr>
        </inquiry>
      </report>
    </reportResponse>
```

How can I remove one tab after first line so that this xml string should look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<reportResponse>
  <report>
    <inquiry>
      <agencyId>32</agencyId>
      <archiveId>4055062521111790</archiveId>
      <originalArchiveId>0</originalArchiveId>
      <sequenceNr>0</sequenceNr>
    </inquiry>
  </report>
</reportResponse>
```

Comment: Are you happy to actually reformat the XML completely, or should it be the same format as it currently is, *just* removing a single tab from each line?

Comment: Yes the format should be same as it is now. Just removing tab from each line but of course starting from second line.

Comment: Sounds like you could just read the whole file as text (in the appropriate encoding), remove a leading tab from each line *if there is one*, and write it out again. No risk of changing normalization, other indentation etc.

Comment: Do you really need to remove the "tab", which is actually 4 spaces in this snippet? Whitespace outside tags isn't significant in XML. Unless you display the file as text to a UI, any parser will *remove* the whitespace. GUIs (including browsers) will use their own transformations to display the actual XML data. In any case, the desired indentation shown is the default used by XmlWriter with the `Indented` setting. You can parse the XML text and serialize it back to a string.

Comment: My application will save xml string into database and will be used by other applications from other users. There in some view xml string has to be displayed in required format which I have requested. So the xml string has to be generated without one extra tab.

Comment: *"My application will save xml string into database"* What is your database and its version?

Comment: please add all required details to your question

Comment: Looks like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68073898/3744182) to [Format XML string to print friendly XML string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1123718/3744182) does what you need, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/Li4JNc for a demo.  Using that answer, the XML is reindented but the XML declaration declaration (including the encoding) is preserved.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky. This is MS SQL server database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `System.Xml.Linq`

```cs
string xml = """
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
        <reportResponse>
            <report>
            <inquiry>
                <agencyId>32</agencyId>
                <archiveId>4055062521111790</archiveId>
                <originalArchiveId>0</originalArchiveId>
                <sequenceNr>0</sequenceNr>
            </inquiry>
            </report>
        </reportResponse>
    """;

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
xml = $"""
    {doc.Declaration}
    {doc}
    """;

Console.WriteLine(xml);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Result:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<reportResponse>
  <report>
    <inquiry>
      <agencyId>32</agencyId>
      <archiveId>4055062521111790</archiveId>
      <originalArchiveId>0</originalArchiveId>
      <sequenceNr>0</sequenceNr>
    </inquiry>
  </report>
</reportResponse>
```

But you will have to ensure that you store the XML in the stated UTF-16 format.

Comment: encoding is not always UTF-16 in response. It can also be UTF-8 or iso-8859-1 or may be some else. Will this solution work any encoding format?

Comment: Strings are always UTF-16 in .NET anyway. This matter only if you, e.g., store this to a file. Then you could use a `XmlWriter` which allows specifying an encoding through `XmlWriterSettings`.