# Why is the XmlWriter always outputting utf-16 encoding?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlwriter

I have this extension method

```
    public static string SerializeObject<T>(this T value)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));           
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
                       {
                        Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(true), 
                        Indent = false, 
                        OmitXmlDeclaration = false,
                        NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.None
                       };

        using(var stringWriter = new StringWriter()) 
        {
            using(var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, settings)) 
            {
                serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, value);
            }

            return stringWriter.ToString();
        }
    }
```

but whenever I call this it has an encoding of `utf-16` specified, ie `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to put an encoding attribute to xml other that utf-16 with XmlWriter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427725/how-to-put-an-encoding-attribute-to-xml-other-that-utf-16-with-xmlwriter)

Comment: I've realised that this is a dupe, so vote to close

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Strings are UTF-16, so writing to a StringWriter will always use UTF-16. If that's not what you want, then use some other `TextWriter` derived class, with the encoding you like.

Comment: Shakes head. So what's the point then of having an encoding property on the XmlWriterSettings. Yes a string is UTF-16, but if we're serializing to a string, its because we're about to write to a file or something, and we want the encoding attribute of xml declaration to match the real encoding of the file we create, and this is unlikely to be UTF-16.

Comment: @user don't serialize to a string  go directly to a Stream.

Comment: OK. That makes more sense.

Comment: Yeah, you're using `StringWriter`, so by default it's Unicode (UTF-16) . If I do `using(var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("MyFile.xml", settings)` and do a manual `xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("SomeRootElement"); xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();`, then load it back in: `XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument(); xml.Load("MyFile.xml"); byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(xml.OuterXml); string xmlDoc = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes);`, it is UTF-8 - just FYI that you can dump it to a file and read it back in, then delete the file. Alternatively, use `StringWriter`, just specify `Encoding.UTF8`.

Comment: I think many have missed the point. It saves it as UTF-8, and lies and marks it as UTF-16.

Comment: @DougRoyer Except no, when you write an XML document, it isn't going to automatically write an encoding attribute. You have to specify for it to write that attribute. The code supplied in the OP's question doesn't do that. They are talking about the particular encoding that the content just happens to have and using that encoding attribute as an example of what the content falls under.

Comment: @DougRoyer And no, the string WAS being output to the document as UTF-16. The OP needed UTF-8. You can set the settings to UTF-8, but if your StringWriter encoding isn't also UTF-8, it will output UTF-16.

Answer (score 24):

As far as I know, StringWriter class will always use UTF 16 encoding when serializing to string.  You can write your own override class that accepts a different encoding:

```
public class StringWriterWithEncoding : StringWriter
{
    private readonly Encoding _encoding;

    public StringWriterWithEncoding()
    {
    }

    public StringWriterWithEncoding(IFormatProvider formatProvider)
        : base(formatProvider)
    {
    }

    public StringWriterWithEncoding(StringBuilder sb)
        : base(sb)
    {
    }

    public StringWriterWithEncoding(StringBuilder sb, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
        : base(sb, formatProvider)
    {
    }


    public StringWriterWithEncoding(Encoding encoding)
    {
        _encoding = encoding;
    }

    public StringWriterWithEncoding(IFormatProvider formatProvider, Encoding encoding)
        : base(formatProvider)
    {
        _encoding = encoding;
    }

    public StringWriterWithEncoding(StringBuilder sb, Encoding encoding)
        : base(sb)
    {
        _encoding = encoding;
    }

    public StringWriterWithEncoding(StringBuilder sb, IFormatProvider formatProvider, Encoding encoding)
        : base(sb, formatProvider)
    {
        _encoding = encoding;
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return (null == _encoding) ? base.Encoding : _encoding; }
    }
}
```

So you can use this instead:

```
using(var stringWriter = new StringWriterWithEncoding( Encoding.UTF8))
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: It does put that in the file, it lies. It puts UTF-8 in the file. It put UTF-8 in the file, yet sets the header to: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>

Comment: @DougRoyer Except no, when you write an XML document, it isn't going to automatically write an encoding attribute. You have to specify for it to write that attribute. The code supplied in the OP's question doesn't do that. They are talking about the particular encoding that the content just happens to have and using that encoding attribute as an example of what the content falls under.

Comment: @DougRoyer And no, it was writing the string as UTF-16. The OP needed it to be UTF-8. You can set the settings to UTF-8, but if your StringWriter encoding isn't also UTF-8, it will output UTF-16.

Answer (score 4):

As the accepted answer says, `StringWriter` is UTF-16 (Unicode) by default and design.  If you want to do it by getting a UTF-8 string in the end, there are 2 ways I can give you to get it done:

**Solution #1 (not very efficient, bad practice, but gets the job done):**  Dump it to a text file and read it back in, delete the file *(probably only suitable for small files, if you even want to do this at all - just wanted to show it could be done!)*

```
public static string SerializeObject<T>(this T value)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));           
    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
                   {
                    Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(true), 
                    Indent = false, 
                    OmitXmlDeclaration = false,
                    NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.None
                   };


    using(var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("MyFile.xml", settings)) 
    {
        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, value);
    }

    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.Load("MyFile.xml");
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml.OuterXml);        
    File.Delete("MyFile.xml");

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

}
```

**Solution #2 (better, easier, more elegant solution!):** Do it like you have it, using `StringWriter`, but use its `Encoding` property to set it to UTF-8:

```
public static string SerializeObject<T>(this T value)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));           
    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
                   {
                    Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(true), 
                    Indent = false, 
                    OmitXmlDeclaration = false,
                    NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.None
                   };

    using(var stringWriter = new UTF8StringWriter())
    {
        using(var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, settings)) 
        {
            serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, value);
        }

        return stringWriter.ToString();
    }
}

public class UTF8StringWriter : StringWriter
{
    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get
        {
            return Encoding.UTF8;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The bug is that it actually puts UTF-8 in the XML file it tagged as UTF-16.

Comment: @DougRoyer Except no, when you write an XML document, it isn't going to automatically write an encoding attribute. You have to specify for it to write that attribute. The code supplied in the OP's question doesn't do that. They are talking about the particular encoding that the content just happens to have and using that encoding attribute as an example of what the content falls under.

Comment: @DougRoyer And the bug is that they were writing UTF-16 string content to their XML when they actually needed it to be UTF-8. You can set the settings to UTF-8, but if your StringWriter encoding isn't also UTF-8, it will output UTF-16.

Answer (score 4):

as @john-saunders mentioned in his answer:

> StringWriter will always use UTF-16

So i used MemoryStream for this purposes.

In my case i using windows-1251 encoding.

```
var xmlSstring = "";
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
    {
        Indent = true,
        Encoding = encoding
    };

    using (var xmlTextWriter = XmlWriter.Create(ms, settings))
    {
        doc.Save(xmlTextWriter);
        xmlString = encoding.GetString(ms.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should derive a new class from StringWriter which has an overriden encoding property.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use a class that derives from `StringWriter`, then in your case, you could simply set the `OmitXmlDeclaration` to `false` and declare your own, just as I do below:

```
 public static string Serialize<T>(this T value, string xmlDeclaration = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>") where T : class, new()
        {
            if (value == null) return string.Empty;

            using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
                {
                    Indent = true,
                    OmitXmlDeclaration = xmlDeclaration != null,
                };

                using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, settings))
                {
                    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

                    xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, value);

                    var sb = new StringBuilder($"{Environment.NewLine}{stringWriter}");

                    sb.Insert(0, xmlDeclaration);

                    return sb.ToString();
                }
            }
```