# How do I include a preamble in my request XML?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I'm using `ObjectContent` to build an XML request like so:

```
private HttpRequestMessage CreateRequest<T>(T content, HttpMethod method) where T : class
{
    // create http message request
    var request = CreateRequest(method);

    // set contents of the HTTP message
    var xmlFormatter = new XmlMediaTypeFormatter
                           {
                               Indent = true,
                               UseXmlSerializer = true
                           };

    var objectContent = new ObjectContent<T>(content, xmlFormatter);
    request.Content = objectContent;

    // return HttpRequestMessage
    return request;
}
```

This works well! But, the output doesn't include the XML preamble, e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

**How can I encourage the `XmlSerializer` to include that line?**

Comment: If it works well then why do you need the XMlDeclaration?

Comment: The service I'm calling requires it, unfortunately :/

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't figure out how to do this with `ObjectContent` so I just serialized it first, and then passed it to the request via `StreamContent`:

```
private HttpRequestMessage CreateRequest<T>(T content, HttpMethod method) where T : class
{
    var request = CreateRequest(method);
    var encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    var xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true, Encoding = encoding };

    // StringWriterWithEncoding courtesy of http://stackoverflow.com/a/9459212/29
    using (var stringWriter = new StringWriterWithEncoding(encoding))
    using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, xmlWriterSettings))
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, content);
        request.Content = new StringContent(stringWriter.ToString(), encoding);
    }

    return request;
}
```

Comment: I am sitting the exact same situation, just cant believe there is no default way of forcing in the preamble / declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Your old solution was so very close to do it right.

It is possible to change the OmitXmlDeclaration on the setting inside a overridden class like so

```
    public class CustomXmlMediaTypeFormatter : XmlMediaTypeFormatter
    {
        public CustomXmlMediaTypeFormatter()
        {
            UseXmlSerializer = true;
            WriterSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;
        }
    }
```

Took me a while to figure out as well, but people should know, that it is possible just by setting the WriterSettings to not omit the preamble.

Comment: Well found!  The comment on the `OmitXmlDeclaration` property is misleading:

`// Returns: true to omit the XML declaration; otherwise, false. The default is false, an XML declaration is written.`. 

The default is infact `true` when `UseXmlSerializer = true`