# XmlWriter leave element open

Tags: c#, xml, xmpp, xmlwriter

I am looking at the XMPP protocol and testing some basic interaction with a server.
XMPP interacts by exchanging XML forward and backwards, but this XML is part of an ongoing stream, effectively building a document as it goes.

I have tried to reproduce this using an XmlWriter and although I can create the Xml almost exactly as required, I can't seem to prevent the writer from closing the Xml Element. For example to open the connection you send a `<stream:stream ... >` element (to be closed at some later point in the interaction). Using an XmlWriter will always close this element such as: `<stream:stream ... />` which I don't want because sending the close `/>` will cause the server to close the stream.

Is there a way to get an XmlWriter to leave the element "open" but still retrieve the data contained within? Of course I can just do a string replace on the element to get rid of the '/' but I'd prefer to find a neater method of doing this if possible.

The initial message to send to the server looks like this:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><stream:stream from="email@address.com" to="address.com" version="1.0" xml:lang="en" xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" >`

So far my code is:

```
private string CreateStreamHeader(string from, string to, double version)
{
    Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Encoding = encoding;
    using(var output = new StringWriterWithEncoding(sb, encoding))
    {
        using(XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(output, settings))
        {
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement("stream", "stream", "http://etherx.jabber.org/streams");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("from", from);
            writer.WriteAttributeString("to", to);
            writer.WriteAttributeString("version", version.ToString("0.0"));
            writer.WriteAttributeString("xml", "lang", null, "en");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "jabber:client");
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

And this code produces:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><stream:stream from="email@address.com" to="address.com" version="1.0" xml:lang="en" xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" />` <-- note the /> here

Note: the StringWriterWithEncoding is the one explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427725/how-to-put-an-encoding-attribute-to-xml-other-that-utf-16-with-xmlwriter)

Comment: Show us your code so far, or a simplified example of it.

Comment: @gingerbreadboy I've updated it to give some more information now. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably consider one of the existing libraries linked to at [xmpp.org](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/).  Treating namespace declarations as if they are attributes will come back to haunt you later.

As to your question, manually serialize the `stream:stream` start tag, and only use XmlWriter for full stanzas.